# $window.open - it causes logout on firefox, but on chrome it does work

Tags: angularjs

```
$stateProvider.state({
            name: 'application',
            onEnter: function($window) {
                $window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
            },
            url : 'http://www.google.com'
        })
```

It properly move to google.com on pressing button. However, my problem is that in case Chrome it does work properly (after clicking back in browser it returns and keep session). The same story in case of Opera.

However, in case of firefox it loses session (after clicking back I must login again).

Can you help me where the bug is ?

Second, less important thing, is that in prompt of button I can see `home/http://www.google.com` instead of `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: It seems unusual to be calling window.open in a state event handler. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve at a higher level?

Comment: @JC. Simply I have ready implementation and I must add link to external website. Each button is connected to state, so I assume that I should also this button connect to state.